# query with dependent subqueries too slow

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, query-performance

```
select  mt.from_user, mt.to_user, mt.group_id, g.name, g.created_by as adminuser,
        msg.*, 
    (
        SELECT  id
            from  messages
            where  t.thread_id = thread_id
              and  id NOT IN (
                SELECT  message_id  from  message_deleted
                    where  user_id=275  and  status='deleted' )
            order by  CreatedDate DESC
            limit  1
    ) as msgid, 
    (
        SELECT  CreatedDate
            from  messages
            where  t.thread_id = thread_id
              and  id NOT IN (
                SELECT  message_id  from  message_deleted
                    where  user_id=275  and  status='deleted'  )
            order by  CreatedDate DESC
            limit  1
    ) as msgDate
    from  user_thread as t
    left join  message_thread as mt  ON t.thread_id = mt.id
    left join  group_master as g  ON mt.group_id = g.id
    left join  group_member as gm  ON gm.group_id = g.id
    left join  messages as msg  ON t.thread_id = msg.thread_id
    where  (      gm.user_id=275
              or  msg.from_id=275
              or  msg.to_id=275
           )
      and  t.status = 'Active'
    group by  mt.id
    order by  msgDate DESC
```

This takes about 50 sec.

In above code, I have try to split above query and note that below subquery take too much time to execute. Can I convert subquery into join. please help me. I am stuck.please note that all tables which are joined are necessary.

```
    (
        SELECT  id
            from  messages
            where  t.thread_id = thread_id
              and  id NOT IN (
                SELECT  message_id  from  message_deleted
                    where  user_id=275  and  status='deleted' )
            order by  CreatedDate DESC
            limit  1
    ) as msgid, 
    (
        SELECT  CreatedDate
            from  messages
            where  t.thread_id = thread_id
              and  id NOT IN (
                SELECT  message_id  from  message_deleted
                    where  user_id=275  and  status='deleted'  )
            order by  CreatedDate DESC
            limit  1
    ) as msgDate
```

Comment: I you don't come to a solution consider adjusting memory settings or a hardware upgrade. SSD or ramdisk works like a charm to speed up things.

Comment: sub query usually don't speed up things :-). Apart from that: the group-by line has nothing to do there, I should actually trigger an error message. As you do not have an aggregation function like count() or sum() in your query

Comment: and what do you try to retrieve by these subqueries?

Comment: Perhaps try putting this onto `Code Review`

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Only one question per question, please. Your codeigniter question is your second one. Please read this.  http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/271056/ and pay special attention to the second on query performance. Please [edit] your question to add necessary details.

Comment: @MartinB.  If only throwing hardware (RAM, SSD) at this sort of thing would help! It probably won't help at all. It certainly won't help scale up.

Comment: Please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE` for each table and `EXPLAIN SELECT ...`

Answer (score 0):

First, You are misusing a notorious MySQL extension to `GROUP BY`. This will probably cause your results to be unpredictable. Read this. https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-handling.html

Second, You have a couple of nested dependent subqueries. The first of them is this.

```
(select id 
   from messages
  where t.thread_id = thread_id
    and id NOT IN (select message_id
                     from message_deleted
                    where user_id=275
                      and status='deleted') 
  order by CreatedDate DESC limit 1) as msgid
```

Such nested dependent subqueries perform notoriously badly. They're even worse when they contain `LIMIT` clauses. Your route to fixing this is refactoring into an independent query and then JOINing it.

This may work as a replacement for the query to find the most recent undeleted message on the thread.

```
          SELECT MAX(m.id) id, m.thread_id
            FROM messages m
            LEFT JOIN message_deleted d 
                        ON m.id = d.id
                       AND d.user_id = 275
                       AND d.status = 'deleted'
           WHERE d.id IS NULL
           GROUP BY m.thread_id
```

This uses the `LEFT JOIN .... IS NULL` pattern in place of `NOT IN`. It's faster.  It uses the `MAX(id)` method of finding the most recent row in a table in place of the `ORDER BY CreatedDate DESC LIMIT 1` method, which is also much faster. It's good because it's guaranteed to generate either 0 or 1 row per value of `thread_id`. That means you can use it in a `LEFT JOIN ... ON ... thread_id` operation and not add any rows to your result set.

You can test this subquery by running it. Then you JOIN it, as if it were a table, to the rest of your query, something like this.

```
SELECT whatever,
       q.id, r.CreatedDate
  FROM whatever
  LEFT JOIN (
          SELECT MAX(m.id) id, m.thread_id
            FROM messages m
            LEFT JOIN message_deleted d 
                        ON m.id = d.id
                       AND d.user_id = 275
                       AND d.status = 'deleted'
           WHERE d.id IS NULL
           GROUP BY m.thread_id
       ) q ON q.id = t.id
  LEFT JOIN messages r ON r.id = q.id
```

The second `LEFT JOIN` operation here is used to retrieve the `CreatedDate` value of the newest undeleted message from the messages table.

Comment: Dear StackOverflow colleagues: I wish I knew of a good tutorial about this kind of problem. It comes up a lot. Any pointers?

Comment: I am getting null in id and CreatedDate